# ExpandableListView hides TextView in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview

as you can try from my code below the TestView is covered by 
the ExpandableListViewand is not visibile.
I would like it to be on top, then the ExpandableListView below and on the bottom a LinearLayout with some elements.

Do you know why this happens and how to solve?
Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >

<TextView
             android:id="@+id/tvteam"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/listViewTeams"
            android:text="test"

              />


    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewTeams"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="tvteam"
         />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/llbottom"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"

        >
         <EditText
             android:id="@+id/searchteam"
              android:layout_width="@dimen/editwidthsml"
             android:layout_height="@dimen/editheightsml"
            android:singleLine="true" 
           android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
           android:layout_margin="2dp"
             android:hint="@string/searchteam" />
          <LinearLayout 

           android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3"
        >
        <Button 
             android:id="@+id/btnfilterteams1"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/selectorface"
            android:text="@string/tourneyteams"
           android:tag="btnfilterteams1"
            />

        <Button 
               android:id="@+id/btnfilterteams2"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/selectorface"
              android:text="@string/allteams"
                android:tag="btnfilterteams2"
            />

        <Button 
          android:id="@+id/btnfilterteams3"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/selectorface"
              android:text="@string/playersonly"
                android:tag="btnfilterteams3"
            />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: At the moment I put the textview out of the relativelayout and wapped all in a LinearLayout but I guess there are better ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 android:layout_below="tvteam"
```

This is wrong, should be:

```
 android:layout_below="@+id/tvteam"
```

Answer (score 0):

try to remove `android:layout_above="@+id/listViewTeams"`